# Angular 4, работа с сервисом в шаблоне

Tags: angular2

Имеется шаблон вида: `<li *ngIf="userService.isLoggedIn">`.
Не хочется напрямую выводить сервис в шаблон, а, например, присвоить какой-то переменной: this.isLoggedIn = userService.isLoggedIn, но в данном случае изменения сервиса не затрагивают объявленную переменную, там по прежнему будет старое значение. Можно использовать Subject и подписываться на него, но получается громоздко, например: `this.userService.isLoggedIn.asObservable().subscribe(isLoggedIn => this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn);`

Есть ли еще какие-нибудь решения? И насколько вообще правильно/неправильно  работать с сервисом в шаблоне.

Comment: использовать в шаблоне норм практика, если не прав, то объясните почему нет... просто в конструкторе компонента ставь модификатор `public` , чтобы было ясно, где искать... ну и старое значение там не будет, если у тебя синглтон и сервис инициализируется при старте приложения, тут скорее дело вкуса...

Comment: Ещё как вариант можно написать функцию или геттер, который будет возвращать значение из сервиса (и в шаблоне обращаться к этой функции/геттеру). Но напрямую обращаться мне больше нравится

Comment: @Artsiom, не совсем нормальная. Считается, что это увеличивается связность между компонентами кода, и будет проблематично что-то изменить, если вдруг понадобится

Comment: @Grundy я с вами соглашусь, в иных случаях я тоже делаю обёртку внутри компонента, но если дело касается userService, то удобнее с ним работать в шаблоне тк изменяться там нечему, в ином случае выйдет тонна кода в каждом компоненте

Comment: @Artsiom, удобнее до момента, пока какое-то из полей используемое во вью не будет вынесено в другой сервис например. В идеале это все должно было решаться с помощью разбиения компонентов на более мелкие, тогда в каждом компоненте не будет тонны кода

Comment: @Grundy ну здесь вы говорите исключительно про best practicies, но по факту у нас естт заказчик, сроки, настроение и ещё куча факторов, разбивать каждый компонент на микро не есть хороший вариант, я могу сделать вывод, что правильный ответ здесь будет в зависимости от конкретной ситуации

Comment: @Artsiom, ну так и автор вопроса про них спрашивает :-)

Comment: @Grundy думаю автору хватит двух разных точек зрения, чтобы сделать выводы, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Напишите функцию в контроллере:

```
isAuthenticate() { 
    return userService.isLoggedIn;
}
```

Соответственно в разметке:

```
<li *ngIf="isAuthenticate()">
```

В случае, изменения значения в сервисе, вы его на очередном цикле получите в своём контроллере.